# Why do multiple EXISTS break a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I am attempting to include a new table with values that need to be checked and included in a stored procedure. Statement 1 is the existing table that needs to be checked against, while statement 2 is the new table to check against.

I currently have 2 `EXISTS` conditions that function independently and produce the results I am expecting. By this I mean if I comment out Statement 1, statement 2 works and vice versa. When I put them together the query doesn't complete, there is no error but it times out which is unexpected because each statement only takes a few seconds.

I understand there is likely a better way to do this but before I do, I would like to know why I cannot seem to do multiple exists statements like this? Are there not meant to be multiple `EXISTS` conditions in the `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 S    
WHERE
--Statement 1
EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM table2 P WITH (NOLOCK)
      INNER JOIN table3 SA ON SA.ID = P.ID
   WHERE P.DATE = @Date AND P.OTHER_ID = S.ID
   AND 
   (
      SA.FILTER = ''
      OR 
      (
          SA.FILTER = 'bar'
          AND 
          LOWER(S.OTHER) = 'foo'
       )
    )
)
OR 
(
   --Statement 2
   EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT 1
      FROM table4 P WITH (NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN table5 SA ON SA.ID = P.ID
      WHERE P.DATE = @Date 
            AND P.OTHER_ID = S.ID 
            AND LOWER(S.OTHER) = 'foo'
    )
)
```

**EDIT:** I have included the query details. Table 1-5 represent different tables, there are no repeated tables.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I [can't reproduce this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=466a3c2c6546ead7f91f4df53df44389) If your query is timing out, I'd check the execution plan and see what is bloating your query. You only posted pseudo code which makes this pretty hard.

Comment: @scsimon I am surprised it is the queries themselves. I have included the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found putting 2 `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` condition made the whole process take significantly longer. What I found fixed it was using `UNION` and keeping the `EXISTS` in separate queries. The final result looked like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 S    
WHERE
--Statement 1
   EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT 1
      FROM table2 P WITH (NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN table3 SA ON SA.ID = P.ID
      WHERE P.DATE = @Date AND P.OTHER_ID = S.ID
      AND 
      (
         SA.FILTER = ''
         OR 
         (
             SA.FILTER = 'bar'
             AND 
             LOWER(S.OTHER) = 'foo'
          )
       )
   )

UNION

--Statement 2 
SELECT *
FROM table1 S    
WHERE
   EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT 1
      FROM table4 P WITH (NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN table5 SA ON SA.ID = P.ID
      WHERE P.DATE = @Date 
            AND P.OTHER_ID = S.ID 
            AND LOWER(S.OTHER) = 'foo'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Too long to comment.

Your query as written seems correct. The timeout will only be able to be troubleshot from the execution plan, but here are a few things that could be happening or that you could benefit from.

- Parameter sniffing on `@Date`. Try hard-coding this value and see if you still get the same slowness
- No covering index on `P.OTHER_ID` or `P.DATE` or `P.ID` or `SA.ID` which would cause a table scan for these predicates
- Indexes for the above columns which aren't optimal (including too many columns, etc)
- Your query being serial when it may benefit from parallelism.
- Using the `LOWER` function on a database which doesn't have a case sensitive collation (most don't, though this function doesn't slow things down that much)
- You have a bad query plan in cache. Try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` at the bottom so [you get a new query plan](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/using-the-option-recompile-option-for-a-statement/). This is also done when comparing the speed of two queries to ensure they aren't using cached plans, or one isn't when another is which would skew the results.

Since your query is timing out, [try including the estimated execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/07/comparing-estimated-actual-execution-plans-sql-server/) and post it for us at [past the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: You are correct, the execution plan was hiding how much the subtree cost was. It turns out putting the 2 exists together skyrockets the processing power required and makes the plan take almost 50x longer to complete.

Comment: Then i'd just do one into a temp and then do the other or tune appropriately.

Comment: I posted the answer to this but I found unioning to be the most efficient solution

Comment: That’d be one way fornsure